# C++ merge sort implement

Tags: c++, vector, mergesort

I want to implement merge sort with C++ and vector(considering input number of integers is unknown). I tried to implement based on the Bottom-up implementation thought through wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort. I came out with the following code. It can pass compile but dies when entered numbers. I do not know what's going wrong here.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void BottomUpMerge(vector<int>, vector<int>::iterator, vector<int>::iterator, vector<int>::iterator, vector<int>);

void BottomUpSort(int n, vector<int> A, vector<int> B)
{
  int width;

  /* Each 1-element run in A is already "sorted". */

  /* Make successively longer sorted runs of length 2, 4, 8, 16... until whole array is sorted. */
  for (width = 1; width < n; width = 2 * width){
    vector<int>::iterator leftstart;

    /* Array A is full of runs of length width. */
    for (leftstart = A.begin(); leftstart <= A.end(); leftstart = leftstart + 2 * width){
        /* Merge two runs: A[i:i+width-1] and A[i+width:i+2*width-1] to B[] */
        /* or copy A[i:n-1] to B[] ( if(i+width >= n) ) */
        vector<int>::iterator rightstart;
        vector<int>::iterator rightend;
        if(leftstart+width >= A.end()){
            rightstart = A.end();
        }
        else{
            rightstart = leftstart+width;
        }
        if(leftstart+2*width >= A.end()){
            rightend = A.end();
        }
        else{
            rightend = leftstart+2*width;
        }

        BottomUpMerge(A, leftstart, rightstart, rightend, B);
    }

    /* Now work array B is full of runs of length 2*width. */
    /* Copy array B to array A for next iteration. */
    /* A more efficient implementation would swap the roles of A and B */
    A = B;
    /* Now array A is full of runs of length 2*width. */
    }
}

void BottomUpMerge(vector<int> A, vector<int>::iterator iLeft, vector<int>::iterator iRight, vector<int>::iterator iEnd, vector<int> B)
{
  vector<int>::iterator i0 = iLeft;
  vector<int>::iterator i1 = iRight;
  vector<int>::iterator j = B.begin() + distance(iLeft, A.begin()); //iterator for vector B

  /* While there are elements in the left or right lists */
  for (; j != B.end(); j++){
    /* If left list head exists and is <= existing right list head */
    if (i0 < iRight && (i1 >= iEnd || *i0 <= *i1)){
        *j = *i0;
        i0 = i0 + 1;
    }
    else{
        *j = *i1;
        i1 = i1 + 1;
    }
  }
}


int main(){
    int input;
    vector<int> numbers;    //input vector of numbers

    cout << "Please input the numbers to be sorted:" << endl;
    while(cin>>input){
        numbers.push_back(input);
    }

    int length = numbers.size();
    vector<int> sorted = numbers;   //work vector ensure has the same size of the original vector

    BottomUpSort(length, numbers, sorted);

    vector<int>::iterator it;
    for(it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << (*it) << '\n';
    }

    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: "Dies when entering numbers" is not descriptive enough of the error/unexpected behavior you're seeing; can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here:

```
BottomUpMerge(A, leftstart, rightstart, rightend, B);
...

void BottomUpMerge(vector<int> A, vector<int>::iterator iLeft, ...)
{
  ...
```

You are passing the vectors by value, which means that `BottomUpMerge` is handling *copies* of them. But the iterators still point back into the originals, and hilarity ensues. Pass the vectors by reference, and at least some of these problems should disappear.

(You should have discovered this when you were testing this function, before you wrote all of the surrounding code. **Never add to code that doesn't work.**)